# reatach to XMPP Connection on server restart

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

I am using xmpp via smack. 
I have connection C1 which is connected to A1 and sending via C1 messages .

lets say I have sent via C1 100 messages (downstream messages from my server down to my clients ) acked them and awaiting receipts to inform me that the message got to the device .
I have got 90 receipts  but there are 10 devices whom didnt acked me back .

and now I need to restart my webapp and to close C1 , how can I on server up reatch to this C1 in order to get those 10 receipts ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the session should expire after a while. When that happens or on admin trigger the unacked message should go to XMPP server offline message store.

Answer (score 0):

It's not important to reattach to C1, if you open a new socket with the same `sender id`, GCM XMPP server will try to resend any unAcked messages.

Note that, on this new socket, you should have a new transaction (I mean an upstream or downstream initiated by your clients or server), to start receiving all of your remaining messages from GCM (in youe case 10 receipts).

Comment: in your note you are saying new transaction , I am wirking with smack libary in java , what do u mean ?